# How to replace a word with new word in string using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

How can I find the word in string and replace word with new returned string from the function.

I want to remove each `newInfo`related words with the new string.

input is = `"I have a newInfo_1. the colour of newInfo_3 and is like newInfo_2";`

output i want is  = `"I have a <p><span>675768736486898479983</span<</p> the colour of <p><span>642778984296898479983</span></p> and is like <p><span>752138876489379</span></p>"`

I tried this but it's not working

```
String str = "I have a newInfo_1. the colour of newInfo_3 and is like newInfo_2";
int total = str.split("newInfo_").length - 1;

for(int i = 0; i<=total; i++){
String replaceSpan = addTag(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
String regex = "newInfo_"
String replaceString = str.replace(regex , replaceSpan);//
}

    public String addTag(String info){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<p><span>");
        sb.append(info);
        sb.append("</span> </p>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Clearly mention what the input is, what you are printing, what the expected output is, and what the actual output is.

Comment: i just update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example, the created *replaceString* variable isn't used, and it loses the result of the string replacement. Replace *replaceString* with "*str*" and replace the string with the replaced string to keep operating on it. Next replace calling replaceString() with replaceFirst() and add \d to the regexp to include the digit in the target string.

```java
String str = "I have a newInfo_1. the colour of newInfo_3 and is like newInfo_2";
int total = str.split("newInfo_").length;

for(int i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
    String replaceSpan = addTag(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    str = str.replaceFirst("newInfo_\\d", replaceSpan);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

The output:

```
I have a <p><span>09154ae1-1002-46c3-bf58-576769237738</span> </p>.
the colour of <p><span>92fe3e31-ae0d-40a1-ba18-01ab6d8d6327</span> </p> and
is like <p><span>2c7790f7-2219-4800-a301-d11c4e6de8bb</span> </p>
```

You can simplify this a little bit by dropping the split() and checking if there are more matches in the loop with the same output.

```java
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("newInfo_\\d");
    while(true) {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
        if (!matcher.find()) break;
        String replaceSpan = addTag(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        str = matcher.replaceFirst(replaceSpan);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much i write the same code but i was not replacing with same str thankyou but it only replaces till _ not after the underscore

Comment: Use repalceFirst() with \d in the regexp to replace the digit.

Comment: Thankyou , is there a way while iteration I can extract the digit after the ```_```

Comment: If add group to regexp then can access the digit; i.e., `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("newInfo_(\\d)");` and inside loop add;     `System.out.println(matcher.group(1));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233135/discussion-between-jasonm1-and-program).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work fine!

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= total; i++){
        String replaceSpan = addTag(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        String regex = "newInfo_";
        String replaceString = str.replaceAll(regex , replaceSpan);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility.

- create a list of tags that are associated with the actual number of the replacement.  A Map could also be used for this.
- then simply iterate over the list, replacing the proper `new_info` tag number with the associated `span tag`.
- I also changed `addTag` to `makeTag`

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str =
                "I have a newInfo_1. the colour of newInfo_3 and is like newInfo_2";
        
        List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            tags.add(makeTag(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
            String target = "newInfo_" + (i + 1);
            str = str.replace(target, tags.get(i));//
        }
        
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    
    public static String makeTag(String info) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<p><span>");
        sb.append(info);
        sb.append("</span> </p>");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```